# Symfony2 - Compiler Passes

Tags: symfony, parameters

I want to change the value of a parameter located in parameters.yml from my controller
with

```
$this->container->setParameter('myParam','newValue');
```

I get an error : Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag
I really looked for a solution but I have not understood how compile passes work 
does someone can give me a simple example

**UPDATE:**
I have some parameters stored there (my mailbox, the LAPD parameters, etc ..) I would like to give control to the admin to configure it from the dashboard

Comment: You can't change container after building. So, change parameter from controller is impossible.
Can you update question and tell why it need?

Comment: I have some parameters stored there (my mailbox, the LAPD parameters, etc ..)
I would like to give control to the admin to configure it from the dashboard

Comment: This might be useful for you: https://github.com/egzakt/UnifikDatabaseConfigBundle

Comment: thank you Paulpro, it works perfectly